# Large Table in landscape mode not scaling to page

Tags: longtable, landscape

I am trying to fit the following table (from `https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_reports/RR2200/RR2299/RAND_RR2299.pdf`) in landscape mode to a whole page. However, the result is that the table is too small and unreadable, at least in overleaf:

[image]

I have used the online generator for tables from `https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables/load`, which has served me well so far but is failing me with this specific task.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage{booktabs}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{lscape}

    \title{dff}
    \author{Testorossa}
    \date{November 2018}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}

    % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
    % \usepackage{booktabs}
    % \usepackage{lscape}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[]
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
    \toprule
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Incident\\   (Country, Date)\end{tabular} & Description & Peril & Exposure & Sector \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Stuxnet worm \\  (Iran 2010)\end{tabular}} & Cyber weapon causing physical destruction of centrifuges used in the Iranian nuclear program & Degradation and destruction of physical systems & Capital assets & Public \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}DDoS attacks on U.S.\\ banks (USA, 2012)\end{tabular}} & Denial of service attacks on more than 46 major U.S.  financial institutions & Disruption of business & Net income through loss revenue & Banking \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Saudi Aramco (Saudi Arabia, 2012 and 2016)} & Destruction of 35,000 Saudi Aramco computers in 2012; a similar attack occured lately in late 2016 & Destruction of data and systems & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capital asset destruction   \\  Net income loss from disruption\end{tabular} & Oil, gas and chemicals \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Yahoo data breaches (USA, 2013 and 2014)} & Exfiltration of more than 500 million user records, including login information & Exfiltration of customer data & Net income through liability and lost revenue & Technology \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sony Pictures (USA, 2014)} & Exfiltration and leak of sensitive information and business disruption & Exfiltration of company data & Intellectual property, Net income & Media \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GitHub (USA, 2015)} & Large and persistent denial of serviceattack on GitHub & Denial of service & Net income & Technology \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{TV5Monde (France, 2015)} & 18-hour outage of French TV network TV5Monde & Disruption of business & Net income & Media \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Office of PersonnelManagement (USA, 2015)} & Exfiltration of more than 21.5 million highly sensitive PII records. & Exfiltration of customer data & This has no clear mapping to costs in our framework & Public \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Germany parliament\\ (Germany, 2015)\end{tabular}} & Exfiltration of 2,420 secret files from a German parliament database and WikiLeaks release & Exfiltration of organization data &  & Public \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ukraine power grid\\ (Ukraine, 2016)\end{tabular}} & Attack disrupting service of Ukrainian energy distributors, cutting power to 225,000 customers & Business disruption and denial of  service & Direct cost in net income of utilities and systemic cost in net income of users & Utilities \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Democratic National Committee(USA, 2016)} & Exfiltration of campaign documents and presidential election interference & Exfiltration of organization data & This has no clear mapping to costs in our framework & Public \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Bangladesh Central Bank(Bangladesh, 2016)} & Attack leading to an \$81 million heist from the Bangladesh Central Bank & Corruption of data and systems & Loss of \$81 million in assets & Public \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Mossack Fonseca (Panama, 2016)} & Significant data exfiltration leading to 11.5 million leaked documents representing hundreds of thousands of offshore entities & Exfiltration of customer data & Direct costs include loss of IP and net income; systemic costs include loss in client net income & Business andprofessional services \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Dyn (USA, 2016)} & Denial of service attack on domain name service provider Dyn, leading to disruptions for a significant number of customer websites & Denial of service & Direct costs to Dyn’s net income and systemic costs to net income of customers & Technology \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}notPetya\\ (global, 2017)\end{tabular}} & Ransomware attack beginning in Ukraine leading to major disruptions in shipping, advertising, and pharmaceuticals worldwide & Business disruption and destruction of data and systems & Net income losses borne through business interruptions & All \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{WannaCry (global, 2017)} & Ransomware attack leading to major disruptions at hospitals, universities, and business worldwide & Business disruption and destruction of data and systems & Net income losses borne through business interruptions & All \\
    Equifax (USA, 2017) & Loss of 143 million sensitive U.S. PII records & Exfiltration of customer data & Net income loss to Equifax; full PII costs not captured in model & Business and professional services \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

If it is not possible to rectify the table, i.e. make it large enough so that is readable, what are common workarounds to still display this information?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table is to huge that can be fit in one page and in the same time be readable (fonts had to be far smaller than `tiny`).so, one option is:

- break long text in cells into more lines
- split table over two page by use `longtable` or `ltablex`.

with using a `ltablex` you can  relatively simple design column width, however this also can be one in a `longtable` using `p{<width>}` column type.

**edit:** added is `\listoftables` and corrected definition of captions o after first page with table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, makecell}
 \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{landscape}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}  
                                L
             >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}L
             >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
             >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L 
             >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}L
                             @{}}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}\\
    \toprule
Incident  (Country, Date)
    &   Description 
        &   Peril 
            &   Exposure 
                &   Sector   \\ 
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption*{Table~\thetable: My caption (cont.)}\\  % <--- changed, now will not appear in \listoftables
    \toprule
Incident  (Country, Date)
    &   Description
        &   Peril
            &   Exposure
                &   Sector   \\
    \midrule
 \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
Stuxnet worm (Iran 2010)
    &   Cyber weapon causing physical destruction of centrifuges used in the Iranian nuclear program
        &   Degradation and destruction of physical systems 
            &   Capital assets 
                &   Public      \\
    \addlinespace            
DDoS attacks on U.S.  banks (USA, 2012) 
    &   Denial of service attacks on more than 46 major U.S.  financial institutions
        &   Disruption of business 
            &   Net income through loss revenue 
                &   Banking     \\
    \addlinespace
Saudi Aramco (Saudi Arabia, 2012 and 2016) 
    &   Destruction of 35,000 Saudi Aramco computers in 2012; a similar attack occurred lately in late 2016
        &   Destruction of data and systems
            &   Capital asset destruction  Net income loss from disruption
                &   Oil, gas and chemicals \\
    \addlinespace
Yahoo data breaches (USA, 2013 and 2014) 
    &   Exfiltration of more than 500 million user records, including login information
        &   Exfiltration of customer data
            &   Net income through liability and lost revenue
                & Technology    \\
    \addlinespace
Sony Pictures (USA, 2014) 
    &   Exfiltration and leak of sensitive information and business disruption
        &   Exfiltration of company data & Intellectual property, Net income
            & Media             \\
    \addlinespace
GitHub  (USA, 2015) 
    &   Large and persistent denial of serviceattack on GitHub
        &   Denial of service
            &   Net income
                &   Technology  \\
    \addlinespace
TV5Monde  (France, 2015) 
    &   18-hour outage of French TV network TV5Monde
        &   Disruption of business
            &   Net income
                & Media         \\
    \addlinespace
Office of Personnel Management (USA, 2015)
    &   Exfiltration of more than 21.5 million highly sensitive PII records.
        &   Exfiltration of customer data
            &   This has no clear mapping to costs in our framework
                &   Public      \\
    \addlinespace
Germany parliament (Germany, 2015) 
    &   Exfiltration of 2,420 secret files from a German parliament database and WikiLeaks release
        & Exfiltration of organization data
            &   & Public        \\
    \addlinespace
Ukraine power grid  (Ukraine, 2016) 
    &   Attack disrupting service of Ukrainian energy distributors, cutting power to 225,000 customers
        &   Business disruption and denial of  service
            &   Direct cost in net income of utilities and systemic cost in net income of users
                &    Utilities  \\
    \addlinespace
Democratic National Committee (USA, 2016) 
    &   Exfiltration of campaign documents and presidential election interference
        &    Exfiltration of organization data
            &   This has no clear mapping to costs in our framework
                &   Public      \\
    \addlinespace
Bangladesh Central Bank (Bangladesh, 2016) 
    &   Attack leading to an \$81 million heist from the Bangladesh Central Bank
        &   Corruption of data and systems
            &   Loss of \$81 million in assets
                &   Public      \\
    \addlinespace
Mossack Fonseca (Panama, 2016) 
    &   Significant data exfiltration leading to 11.5 million leaked documents representing hundreds of thousands of offshore entities
        &   Exfiltration of customer data
            &   Direct costs include loss of IP and net income; systemic costs include loss in client net income
                &   Business andprofessional services   \\
    \addlinespace
Dyn (USA, 2016)
    &   Denial of service attack on domain name service provider Dyn, leading to disruptions for a significant number of customer websites
        &   Denial of service
            &   Direct costs to Dyn’s net income and systemic costs to net income of customers
                &   Technology  \\
    \addlinespace
notPetya (global, 2017) 
    &   Ransomware attack beginning in Ukraine leading to major disruptions in shipping, advertising, and pharmaceutical worldwide
        &   Business disruption and destruction of data and systems
            &   Net income losses borne through business interruptions
                &   All         \\
    \addlinespace
WannaCry (global, 2017) 
    &   Ransomware attack leading to major disruptions at hospitals, universities, and business worldwide
        &   Business disruption and destruction of data and systems
            &   Net income losses borne through business interruptions
                &   All         \\
    \addlinespace
Equifax (USA, 2017) 
    &   Loss of 143 million sensitive U.S. PII records
        &   Exfiltration of customer data
            &   Net income loss to Equifax; full PII costs not captured in model
                &   Business and professional services  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Zarko, thanks again for the original answer. When I try to include a list of tables in the beginning of the document, every page (currently 4 pages) gets its own entry. Do you know of a workaround for that? Thank you very much

Comment: @Ozaki_san, sorry, but my  original solution is not adopted for use of`\listoftables` for this you need to change `\caption` command after \endfirsthead` to `\caption*{Table~\thetable: My caption (cont.)}\\ `. this is now corrected in answer.